# Inserting current href with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm editing a Wordpress Plugin where I need to track outbound clicks with Google Analytics' Event tracking javascript code. The challenge is, I can only edit the one php file that produces multiple links.  In the code below I just need to replace the part "this.getAttribute('href')" with the href of that link.  How can this be done?  I have tried the this.getAttribute('href') code but it doesn't execute.

```
<a href="http://lifeplace.com.au/" onclick="trackOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', this.getAttribute('href')); return false;" title=""><img class="soliloquy-item-image" src="http://www.96five.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/image.jpg" alt="" title="Lifeplace"></a>
```

Comment: What is the problem? `this.getAttribute('href')` should get the value of the `href` attribute.

Comment: This is the PHP code which produces the code above:

             `$slide .= apply_filters( 'tgmsp_link_output', '<a href="' . esc_url( $image['link'] ) . '" onClick="trackOutboundLink(this, \'Outbound Links\', this.getAttribute(\'href\')); return false;" title="' . esc_attr( $link_title ) . '" ' . $link_target . '>', $id, $image, $link_title, $link_target );`

Comment: Actually - I can just use `$image['link']` to get the individual link. I'll close this question.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply set the href dynamically anytime, to any value:

```
var anchor=document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]; // for the sake of the example
anchor.href="www.google.de";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LP5dC/

Answer (score 0):

Well, are you sure that this.getAttribute('href') does not work?

Can you share trackOutboundLink() function itself?

I have tried same type of function like following, and it alerts right URL:

```
<script>
    function hello(obj, lbl, url) {
        alert(url);
    }
</script>


<a href="http://lifeplace.com.au/" onclick="hello(this, 'Outbound Links', this.getAttribute('href')); return false;" title=""><img class="soliloquy-item-image" src="http://www.96five.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/image.jpg" alt="" title="Lifeplace"></a>
```

So I guess your function itself might have some error while running, or
some other js plugin unbinds onclick event.